# Search Bar & Web View

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to build a simple web browser. The web browser itself works pretty well but when I try to search a url in the search bar I can't return on the keyboard to open the website. How can I fix this?

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    let text = searchBar.text
    let urlSB = NSURL(string: text!)
    let reqSB = NSURLRequest(url:urlSB! as URL)
    self.webView!.loadRequest(reqSB as URLRequest)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")
    let req = NSURLRequest(url:url! as URL)
    self.webView!.loadRequest(req as URLRequest)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: Does the program crash when you press search? Or does it just do nothing?

Comment: No actually nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write a demo for you:

The result:

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2: Type in the url you want to access.

[image]

Step 3: The result, the webView load the url you typed in the searchBar:

[image]

The code is below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.baidu.com")
    let req = NSURLRequest(url:url! as URL)
    self.webView!.loadRequest(req as URLRequest)

    searchBar.delegate = self

}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    let text = searchBar.text
    let urlSB = NSURL(string: text!)
    let reqSB = NSURLRequest(url:urlSB! as URL)
    self.webView!.loadRequest(reqSB as URLRequest)
}

// MARK: - searchbar delegate
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    let urlStr =  "https://" + searchBar.text!

    let url = NSURL(string: urlStr)
    let req = NSURLRequest(url:url! as URL)
    self.webView!.loadRequest(req as URLRequest)

}
```

If your webView did not load the url, and report:

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

You can go to `info.plist` to open the ATS like below, or search the SO to find the detail method:

[image]

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly! Do you also know how to tell the search bar to search in google if just some random words are put in?

Comment: if this, you should join up the google search open sdk or something, because I am in China, baidu developer website have a similarity function, search the word using baidu's search engine, but I don't know the google's this type function is where, but it ought to have.

Comment: I try to use this code, but get error:

let req = NSURLRequest(url:url! as URL)

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisearchbardelegate) methods for UISearchBar and handle everything from there. Also don't forget to set the delegate to the viewcontroller.